# MSSQL 2008 Trigger - where variable = common value between two tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

new to Triggers, i created one that works when i hard code the value that i actually need to list as a *variable*. as in the code, table tbl_measure_stats has trigger StatsTrigger. When tbl_measure_stats changes, it sets tbl_activity.override = 0 WHERE tbl_activity.activityid is supposed to equal the tbl_measure_status.actid. The value in the trigger table is tbl_measures_stats.actid, which is supposed to equal the id of tbl_activity.activityid, whose value override i need to set to 0. How do I code the variable related to 54321? Code is actually simpler than my explanation:

```
USE [TestDB]
GO
/****** OBJECT: Trigger [dbo].[StatsTrigger]  ******/
/****** PURPOSE: detect any field changes in tbl_measure_stats ******/
/****** ... then set tbl_activity.override = 0 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[StatsTrigger] --resides in tbl_measure_stats>Triggers
ON  tbl_measure_stats --table which has the trigger
AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE --when something changes...
AS UPDATE tbl_activity set override = 0 where tbl_activity.activityid = 54321
```

seems like this should be a straight forward solution but i am finding nothing actionable in all my searches. OLD, NEW, inserted for example... i am not getting those to work. Example when trying "inserted":

```
AS UPDATE cpy_activity set porc = 0 where cpy_activity.activityid = inserted.actid
```

returns the error:

```
The multi-part identifier "inserted.actid" could not be bound.
```

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to include `INSERTED` in the `FROM` clause of the query.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[StatsTrigger] --resides in tbl_measure_stats>Triggers
ON  tbl_measure_stats --table which has the trigger
AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE --when something changes...
AS
  UPDATE A SET override = 0 
  FROM tbl_Activity A JOIN INSERTED I ON A.activityID = I.actid
```

Note however that `INSERTED` won't have any rows when the trigger fires because of a `DELETE` action. You should check whether `INSERTED` or `DELETED` have rows and do the right thing accordingly.

Comment: i am humbled at my reliance on stackoverflow. cf_en you hit the proverbial nail squarely on the head. now i change the measure value on the stats page, the trigger runs in mssql, and the override value successfully changes to 0 each time the measure value changes. i hope i can pay this forward, meanwhile many thanks!